# Multiple TextModes in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form of three text boxes having all three inputs only be numbers:

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="Phone" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
```

I was wondering if there is a possibility of having two (or more) `TextMode` for an `<asp:TextBox />`.

For example:

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="Phone Password" />
```

Comment: You'll have to inherit the *TextBox* class and implement it, but yes, possible.

Comment: IMO that does not make sense to have a password of phone mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible.

ASP.NET `TextBox`'s render as HTML `input` elements. The `TextMode` property is used to determine the `type` attribute.

The `input`'s `type` attribute cannot contain a mixture of values, and therefore neither can the ASP.NET `TextBox`.

Comment: Ended up scrapping the initial idea since it's impossible to have multiple values. Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 0):

TextMode attribute accepted only three name

SingleLine - one line textbox
Multiline - Textbox with multiple lines
Password - One line textbox that masks the input

you can use .net Validation Control or jquery validation :)